# In apache-camel, how to embed FTP commands in FTP url?

Tags: ftp, apache-camel

In apache-camel, how can I embed FTP commands (such as MTDM, NLST) in FTP url ?
or can I use FTP command in camel route definition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, the only thing you can do is to execute site commands after a login. See the `siteCommand` option at: http://camel.apache.org/ftp2